# Как правильно тестировать сайт/приложение?

Tags: php, юнит-тесты, тестирование, phpunit

Дано: Laravel, админка + rest api, postgreSQL, phpunit. 
Функционал: статьи с картинками.

Как правильно выполнить unit/feature тестирование?

Возьмем для примера создание статьи. Сразу возникают вопросы:

1. Тестировать сервис и репозиторий отдельно?
2. Для тестирования использовать какую-то другую БД, чтобы не ломать
   заполненную рабочую БД.
3. Как тестировать функционал загрузки картинок? И вообще куда их
   заливать, в ту же папку что и при работе на проде или создавать
   отдельную папку?
4. Нужно ли как-то разграничивать конфиг прод/дев для тестирования?
   Или можно как то подменить конфиг при unit тестировании с помощью
   phpunit?

Comment: Нужно разделять модульное и интеграционное тестирование. Юнит-тесты должны быть молниеносными, поэтому в них никакого обращения к IO. И каждый модуль тестируется отдельно. А в интеграционных тестах уже обращаемся к БД, файловой системе, сети... И тестируем всё вместе.

Answer (score 1):

1 Тестируется вместе - толку от забора, если есть хоть одна дырка?

2. Можно использовать другую, но полностью аутентичную (а кто мешает сделать полный бекап всего перед тестированием, и сохранить в паре-тройке экземпляров, как эталон - на вский случай?)
3. Все нужно делатть, максимально приближенно к продакшн - если перемена папки не критична, то можно.
4. a) Протестировать небольшой блок всего спектра тестирования (немного данных) в обеих режимах и посмотреть различие - если они не существенны, то на dev вполне возиожно.
   b) Конечно, для чистоты эксперимента всегда луже продакшн - но ту смотрите целесообразность и съем нужных параметров.

В общем - чем ближе к продакшн, тем лучше, отходить от этого нужно только в неизбегаемых случаях. Результаты такого теста не только могут послужить аргументацией, но и защитить разработчика - в случае выплывания чего-либо после, если вдруг - в жизни все бывает, но после такого теста (продакшн) предусмотреть все невозможно, и уж конечно, трудно заподозрить разраба в каких-то манипуляциях.

Все имхо, конечно.

Answer (score 1):

В какой то момент своей жизни проекты начинают требовать поддержку и тестирование. Для этого в большинстве случаев приходят к распределению сборок на dev - stage - prod, где каждый элемент - полигон со своей версией кода.

- dev: девелоперский нестабильный полигон, для разработки. Допускаются ошибки, временный offline, ручные правки и так далее.
- stage: пре-prod полигон, для тестирования и выявления ошибок. Допускаются ошибки, не допускается offline, полностью автоматизированный выкат при помощи CI.
- prod: "боевой" полигон. Сюда приходят пользователи. Его падение и найденые баги - причина снижения премий программистам/тестировщикам/девопсам.

Соответственно, на каждом полигоне своя БД, своё окружение и так далее. Как правило это набор отдельных виртуальных машин. Полигонов может быть несколько каждого типа, в зависимости от целей, допускается поднятие sub-dev-полигона при помощи контейниризации непосредственно на машине разработчика.

Так же под каждый полигон в репозитории создаётся своя ветка, коммит в которую должен инициализировать автоматический деплой свежего релиза на полигон. С prod как правило иакое не делают, но это, думаю, исключительно из личных соображений.